# Random <a></a> appeared in HTML code after site went live

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django

Basically my problem is what my question is saying. Before some time we had build
a site using Django and it's build in DB. The site had some problems but we fixed the and we got it live. After that we saw a major mistake in the footer where all the three sections where out
of place. This was do to a random  in the HTML code after we incpect element:

**This is how the footer is implemented in every page.**

```
</body>
{% include "main/footer.html" %}
</html>
```

**Footer code in server**

```
<div class="content">
<section>
    <img class="footer-logo" src="{% static 'material/imgs/logo_banner_inverted.svg' %}" alt="" srcset="">

    <!-- <p><i class="fa fa-folder">&nbsp;</i>dummy@gmail.com</p> -->
</section>

<section class="inline">
    <h4 >Our Social Media</h4>
    <ul class="">
        <li class="no-bottom"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/UNSOCLawAUTh"><i class="fa fa-facebook">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="no-bottom"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/unsoc.law.auth/"><i class="fa fa-instagram">&nbsp;</i>Instagram</a></li>
        <li class="no-bottom"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin ">&nbsp;</i>Linkedin</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>

<section>
    <h4 >Menu</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="">&nbsp;</i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'about-us' %}"><i class="">&nbsp;</i>About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'contact_form' %}"><i class="">&nbsp;</i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
</div>
```

**Footer code presented in live site**

```
<a>
                    </a><div class="content"><a>
                        <section>

                            <img class="footer-logo" src="/static/material/imgs/logo_banner_inverted.svg" alt="" srcset="">

                            <!-- <p><i class="fa fa-folder">&nbsp;</i>dummy@gmail.com</p> -->
                        </section>

                        </a><section class="inline"><a>
                            <h4>Our Social Media</h4>
                            </a><ul class=""><a>
                                </a><li class="no-bottom"><a></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/UNSOCLawAUTh"><i class="fa fa-facebook">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Facebook</a></li>
                                <li class="no-bottom"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/unsoc.law.auth/"><i class="fa fa-instagram">&nbsp;</i>Instagram</a></li>
                                <li class="no-bottom"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin ">&nbsp;</i>Linkedin</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </section>
                        <section>
                            <h4>Menu</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/"><i class="">&nbsp;</i>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/about"><i class="">&nbsp;</i>About us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/contact/"><i class="">&nbsp;</i>Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
```

I am not an expert and I did some research and it just seams like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a bug. It seems that the problem wasn't even at footer but in the page
that was generated in. In the text of the page we had this code `<a class="hover-link a-link" href="some-link"> Link for text </a>`.

Somehow that caused the unexpected bug (if someone knows how that happened I would be happy to learn).

Our solution was to just change it like that `<h><a class="hover-link a-link" href="some-link"> Link for text </a></h>`